# How to update or show data of array in vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli-3

I have created a table which display the product data that was entered by the user and I have placed a column for operations, delete, modify, and details,
but what i don't know is how can I edit or display a particular row on another page?

this is my table

```
<tbody>
            <tr v-for="(item, index) in this.$store.state.pro" :key="item">
              <td class="cart_product">
                <router-link to=""
                  ><img :src="this.$store.state.img" width="70" alt=""
                /></router-link>
              </td>
              <td class="cart_description">
                <h4>
                  <router-link to="">{{ item.nName }}</router-link>
                </h4>
              </td>
              <td class="cart_description">
                <h4>
                  <router-link to="">{{ item.nSub }}</router-link>
                </h4>
              </td>
              <td class="cart_price">
                <p>{{ item.nPrice }}</p>
              </td>
              <td class="cart_description">
                <p>{{ item.nDate }}</p>
              </td>
              <td class="cart_delete">
                <router-link class="cart_quantity_delete" to=""
                  ><i @click="remove(index)" class="fa fa-times text-danger"></i
                ></router-link>
                <router-link class="cart_quantity_delete" to=""
                  ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o text-info"></i
                ></router-link>
                <router-link class="cart_quantity_delete" to="/details/index"
                  ><i class="fa fa-info-circle text-warning"></i
                ></router-link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
```

and this is how the entered data is saved

```
export default {
  name: "login",
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: "",
      price: "",
      sub: "",
      img: "",
      message: "",
      date: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add: function () {
      var New = {
        nName: this.name,
        nPrice: this.price,
        nSub: this.sub,
        nImg: this.img,
        nDate: this.date,
      };
      this.name = "";
      this.price = "";
      this.sub = "";
      this.$store.state.pro.push(New);
      this.$router.push("/control-panel");
    },
  },
  components: { Header, Footer },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass item object or its id to edit method in a row and then use a router push statement with params as id which will route you towards new page. Where you get object details using ID from store or API in the mounted lifecycle hook